# Angular 4 On Meta Tags Rendered

Tags: javascript, angular

Is there an event triggered when Meta tags are rendered?

In my angular 4 app I have some dynamic routes like:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'products/:slug', component: ProductComponent }
];
```

In the ProductComponent (product.component.ts) I get the meta data like below:

```
ngOnInit() {
    let currentSlug = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('slug');

    //Makes ajax call to server to get meta data
    this.MyMetaService.getMeta(currentSlug)
        .subscribe((metadata) = > {
          //Set the page title
          this.title.setTitle(metadata.title);

          this.meta.addTags([
            {name: 'keywords', content: metadata.keywords},
            {name: 'description', content: metadata.description}
        ])
      });
  }
```

Which works fine! Now, I would like to know when the meta tags are fully rendered on page however so far could not figure out how!

I have tried the following but failed:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    const title = $(document).find("title").text();
    console.log('page title is: ', title); //title is still not updated!
  }
```

Surely `setTimeout` works but I am not sure it's not that reliable:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    const title = $(document).find("title").text();
    console.log('page title is: ', title); //Got correct title here!
}, 200);
```

Comment: SetTimeout is a perfect solution and you should go with it...

Comment: You need this for testing? Why not to make `onAfterSetMeta` method and call it inside `subscribe`?

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind this is, you're making an ajax call to retrieve meta tags, that takes time to make roundtrip from server(perhaps few milliseconds). And `ngAfterViewInit` component hook gets called as soon as inner component tree gets rendered.

I don't think so `setTimeout` made it working solely, it is working because you had `200ms` time mentioned.

Comment: Thanks Pankaj! You are right, metadata are content managed by our content team and may get changed from time to time... By making ajax request I was trying to ensure we have the latest data always.